# Is there a video recording app that stores the exact time the video starts (time of day to the millisecond)?

Tags: software-recommendation, video, time, video-capture

I'm looking for an app that will log the exact time a video starts to millisecond precision.

I know that normal .mov videos recorded on Apple's Photos app stores time of day information - but from what I understand, this video format only stores up to the second precision, not the millisecond. I'm not looking for a different video format that would store this (although that would also be of interest)- an app that stores the exact time as a separate text file would suffice.

Of course, if there is a way to accomplish this without a 3rd party app, I would also be interested in this.